# Not able to Initialize SQLiteDatabase helper from Application class

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Trying to initialize SQLiteDatabaseHelper from Application class. 
Application onCreate method. I am able to initialize the Sqlite helper    class

```
public void onCreate() 
{
    super.onCreate();
    appContext = this;

    if(db == null)
    {
        db = new DbClass(appContext);
        db.inititalize();
    }
}
```

The getDb() method returns null.

```
public static DbClass getDb()
    {
        return db;
    }
```

Please help!

Comment: Where are you calling `getDb()`?

Comment: From a Model class. Something like this - App.getDb().get(query);